# How do I convert "2016-Dec-31 23:59:60" UTC time with c++20 chrono to local time and print correct leap seconds?

Tags: c++, time, c++20, c++-chrono, leap-second

The point in time "2016-Dec-31 23:59:60" is a valid time. It is 1483228826 seconds after "1970-Jan-1". The ":60" in the seconds display is correct, because a leap second was inserted there (see wikipedia leap seconds).

My Question: How do I convert a `std::chrono::utc_clock::time_point` with this time to local time (or any timezone) and print it including the ":60" for the seconds part?

```
std::chrono::utc_clock::time_point then;
then += seconds(1483228826);
// Output: 2016-12-31 23:59:60
cout << std::format("{}", time_point_cast<seconds>(then));

// Now convert it to local time
// But this will fail, since zoned_time requires a sys_time
auto local = zoned_time{"Europe/Berlin", then};
```

My problem is: `zoned_time`, which is responsible for handling time zones, only accepts a `sys_time`, not a `utc_time`. But `sys_time` ignores leap seconds.

If I convert my `utc_time` to `sys_time` before constructing a `zoned_time`, my output will be "..23:59:59" and the leap second is lost.

```
auto local = zoned_time{"Europe/Berlin", clock_cast<system_clock>(then));
cout << std::format("{}", time_point_cast<seconds>(local));
```

I think the leap second should be shown even in local time. The leap day after all is also shown in local time.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no clean way to do this.  The time zone database that is used does not recognize leap seconds.

However there is *always* a way to work around things.

For `seconds` precision output it is fairly easy to just brute-force things by running `then` through `get_leap_second_info` to find out if `then` points into a leap second:

```
utc_seconds then{};
then += 1483228826s;
cout << format("{}", then) << '\n';
auto local = zoned_time{"Europe/Berlin", clock_cast<system_clock>(then)};
auto [is_leap_second, elapsed] = get_leap_second_info(then);
if (is_leap_second)
    cout << format("{:%F %H:%M:60}", local) << '\n';
else
    cout << format("{}", local) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01 00:59:60
```

This can be extended to subsecond precision, but is just a little messier.  Here it is for milliseconds:

```
utc_time<milliseconds> then{};
then += 1483228826023ms;
cout << format("{}", then) << '\n';
auto local = zoned_time{"Europe/Berlin", clock_cast<system_clock>(then)};
auto [is_leap_second, elapsed] = get_leap_second_info(then);
if (is_leap_second)
{
    cout << format("{:%F %H:%M:60.}", local);
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(3) << (then-floor<seconds>(then))/1ms << '\n';
}
else
    cout << format("{}", local) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01 00:59:60.023
```

So in a nutshell, find out if you're in a leap second.  If you're not just print the local time.  Otherwise hard-wire the `":60"`, and compute/format the subseconds if applicable.

Comment: Yes, that's a good workaround.

Comment: Would you agree that this is an oversight in the std.chrono library? I would argue that `time_zone` needs a specialization for `utc_time`.
I don't think that the time zone database really needs an entry for leap seconds, though. I thought, leap seconds are inserted globally. To me, a leap second is more like a leap day, rather than a time zone. It might be necessary to have a database for this if we'd want to convert the time from one *calendar* to another.
But time zone conversion should work with no knowledge of leap seconds.

Comment: I would call it a design decision.  A `time_zone` specialization for `utc_time` isn't really sufficient.  The result could not be `local_time` because `local_time` has the semantics of `sys_time + offset`.  Instead you would need a new `time_point` family that has the semantics of `sys_time + offset`.  And it would need to carry the information of if the `time_point` pointed into a leap second.  Otherwise it would not be able to be properly formatted.  This would be a significant design addition. One might also decide to form local times for other clocks as well.

Comment: Additionally, even if one made such additions, you are never going to get a localized `utc_clock::now()` to report hh:mm:60 unless your computer is specifically hooked up to a source for correct time that measures leap seconds (and its std::chrono takes advantage of that).  Most computers get their source of time from time servers such as NTP which smear leap seconds instead of accurately track them.

Comment: The main use case for `utc_time` is to be able to subtract two `time_point`s which straddle one or more leap seconds and have the result include those straddled leap seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of your rational behind the design. Makes sense I guess. Ours is a very specific use-case anyway. We actually record data with exact time stamps and the timeline we display on the computer has to be accurate down to a millisecond. Now I have to research what boost.posix_time.ptime is doing exactly, since I am trying to replace ptime with utc_time. I have seen the :59:60 UTC time with boost, so there is some support for leap seconds.

Comment: @Howard Hinnant  proper NTP does not smear leap seconds, it handles them correctly.  UTC itself is the issue--the same timestamp used for a :60 is also used for the :00 (UTC ignores leap seconds).  Every time there is a leap second, there effectively is a new timezone (the epoch is not a fixed time, it lurches backwards. 
 "the UTC timescale has marched backward relative to the TAI timescale exactly one second on scheduled occasions recorded in the institutional memory of our civilization" --https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/leap.html.  Too many folks in power don't understand leap seconds...

Comment: ...so it will forever be broken, hence the smear hack (which creates other issues)